# How to get information from one page to a different page, and displaying that information in a list box

Tags: asp.net, listbox, submit

I am creating a program in asp.net and I have the first page full of text boxes.
On the second page I have a listbox. I want the information from the text boxes to go into the listbox when clicking on a submit button.

Comment: What have you tried? There are examples all over the internet on [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx) and how to work with [ListBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to store the values in a Session.

For example I have a Login form which I would like to remember the users name once they have logged in, to do this within my C# code I use the following:

```
if (_loginresult == "LoginSuccessful")
{
Session["Username"] = txt_username.Value;
}
```

I can then call the session within my other aspx form using:

```
string Username = (string)(Session["Username"]);
```

And then set it to a text box/list box or label:

```
lbl_UserLoggedIn.Text = "You are logged in as: " + Username;
```